# ListView, erro ao fazer scroll

Tags: android, listview

Criei uma listview personalizada e adicionei 20 itens, quando abro no emulador, só consigo "descer" até o item 15, a partir daí, o emulador para de funcionar. Alguma sugestão?

> E/InputEventReceiver: Exception dispatching input event.

Aparece esse erro. Não consigo chegar ao fim da lista.

Comment: Adicione na descrição da pergunta a mensagem de erro.

Comment: Poste o *Logcat*